# How to Remove Highlighted Row on CheckBox UnChecked?

Tags: jquery

I write the code for table grid having checkboxes. It works well for onclick checkbox, but I want to remove the background color class "highlight-row" once **checkbox unchecked**.

**Here is the code:**

```
if ($(this).prop("checked") == !1) {             
$(this).find("tr").hasClass('highlight-row').removeClass('removeClass');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:You can use `is(":checked")` to see if checkbox is checked or unchecked and accordingly add or remove class from parent `TR`

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {    // use is(":checked") which return true or false         
   $(this).closest("tr").addClass('highlight-row');
} else {
   $(this).closest("tr").removeClass('highlight-row');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently looking for a `tr` which is a child/descandant of the checkbox:

```
$(this).find("tr") //<-- 'this' is the checkbox, so obviously this will fail
```

Rather, to get from the checkbox to the row you need to go up the DOM. Then toggle the class based on whether the checkbox is checked or not.

```
$(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlight-row', $(this).is(':checked'));
```